# Tests are failing in NetBeans because it does not find JARs, which are here

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, junit, jakarta-mail

I have a project that runs successfully on the command line. I had a main() that called a bunch of mail related methods. All that is working fine when in main() of a specific class.

This was not very nice so I decided to put them in a test package so they could run through Junit.

Now, NetBeans is complaining because it does not find the class...

[image: NetBeans' painful complain]

Here is the excerpt of my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.htmlparser.jericho</groupId>
    <artifactId>jericho-html</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks!